# Speed up random weighted choice without replacement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I want to sample ~10⁷ times from a population of ~10⁷ integers without replacements and with weights, each time picking 10 elements. After each sampling I change the weights. I have timed two approaches (python3 and numpy) in the following script. Both approaches seem painfully slow to me, do you see a way of speeding it up?

```
import numpy as np
import random

@profile
def test_choices():
    population = list(range(10**7))
    weights = np.random.uniform(size=10**7)
    np_weights = np.array(weights)

    def numpy_choice():
        np_w = np_weights / sum(np_weights)
        c = np.random.choice(population, size=10, replace=False, p=np_w)

    def python_choice():
        c = []
        while len(c) < 10:
            c += random.choices(population=population, weights=weights, k=10 - len(c))
            c = list(set(c))

    for i in range(10**1):

        numpy_choice()
        python_choice()

        add_weight = np.random.uniform()
        random_element = random.randint(0, 10**7)
        weights[random_element] += add_weight
        np_weights[random_element] += add_weight


test_choices()
```

With the timer result:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    24        10   20720062.0 2072006.2     56.6          numpy_choice()
    25        10   15593925.0 1559392.5     42.6          python_choice()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you replace after each sample of 10?

Comment: yes, the population for each sample is the same, so I replace after each sample of 10. But each sample in itself is without replacement (= the 10 elements of one sample are unique)

Comment: By the way, `weights` and `np_weights` appear to be copies of the same array. Also, do you need `population` to be a list? It seems that you can make it more efficient by using `np.arange`. Part of the overhead is numpy-to-list-to-numpy conversions.

Comment: Also, what is `@profile`?

Comment: yes np_weights is a copy, but it is modified by numpy_choice. @profile is a decorator for line profiler. https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Comment: I'm looking into weighted shuffle algorithms. Sounds like it's something that might work, although it might not be an improvement.

Comment: So you always only change one weight? Is that your actual usage, or did you just make it like that for the question here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or [segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) (not sure what the difference is) could do weight updates and choices in O(log n)... (just an idea, I don't have time now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a comment on jdhesa's answer. The question was if it is useful to consider the case where only one weight is incresed -> Yes it is!

**Example**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_choice_opt(population, weights, k,wc,b_full_wc_calc,ind,value):
    # Get cumulative weights
    if b_full_wc_calc:
        acc=0
        for i in range(weights.shape[0]):
            acc+=weights[i]
            wc[i]=acc
    #Increase only one weight (faster than recalculating the cumulative  weight)
    else:
        weights[ind]+=value
        for i in nb.prange(ind,wc.shape[0]):
            wc[i]+=value

    # Total of weights
    m = wc[-1]
    # Arrays of sample and sampled indices
    sample = np.empty(k, population.dtype)
    sample_idx = np.full(k, -1, np.int32)
    # Sampling loop
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        # Pick random weight value
        r = m * np.random.rand()
        # Get corresponding index
        idx = np.searchsorted(wc, r, side='right')
        # Check index was not selected before
        # If not using Numba you can just do `np.isin(idx, sample_idx)`
        for j in range(i):
            if sample_idx[j] == idx:
                continue
        # Save sampled value and index
        sample[i] = population[idx]
        sample_idx[i] = population[idx]
        i += 1
    return sample
```

**Example**

```
np.random.seed(0)
population = np.random.randint(100, size=1_000_000)
weights = np.random.rand(len(population))
k = 10
wc = np.empty_like(weights)

#Initial calculation 
%timeit numba_choice_opt(population, weights, k,wc,True,0,0)
#1.41 ms ± 9.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Increase weight[100] by 3 and calculate
%timeit numba_choice_opt(population, weights, k,wc,False,100,3)
#213 µs ± 6.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#For comparison
#Please note that it is the memory allcocation of wc which makes
#it so much slower than the initial calculation from above
%timeit numba_choice(population, weights, k)
#4.23 ms ± 64.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea, considering the "delta" of the altered weight so essentially you just need to do `wc[ind:] += value`.

Comment: Putting everything together, the runtime improved by a factor of almost 100 compared to the original approach. Thanks to all of you for your help!

Comment: I think there is a slight bug in this implementation. `sample_idx[i] = population[idx]` should be `sample_idx[i] = idx`, otherwise you will get duplicates

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. I have accelerated my function with Numba but in my tests it is faster also without that.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def numba_choice(population, weights, k):
    # Get cumulative weights
    wc = np.cumsum(weights)
    # Total of weights
    m = wc[-1]
    # Arrays of sample and sampled indices
    sample = np.empty(k, population.dtype)
    sample_idx = np.full(k, -1, np.int32)
    # Sampling loop
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        # Pick random weight value
        r = m * np.random.rand()
        # Get corresponding index
        idx = np.searchsorted(wc, r, side='right')
        # Check index was not selected before
        # If not using Numba you can just do `np.isin(idx, sample_idx)`
        for j in range(i):
            if sample_idx[j] == idx:
                continue
        # Save sampled value and index
        sample[i] = population[idx]
        sample_idx[i] = population[idx]
        i += 1
    return sample
```

Here is a quick comparison

```py
def python_choice(population, weights, k):
    c = []
    while len(c) < 10:
        c += random.choices(population=population, weights=weights, k=10 - len(c))
        c = list(set(c))
    return c

def numpy_choice(population, weights, k):
    w = weights / weights.sum()
    return np.random.choice(population, size=k, replace=False, p=w)

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
population = np.random.randint(100, size=1_000_000)
weights = np.random.rand(len(population))
k = 10
print(python_choice(population, weights, k))
# [96, 99, 90, 46, 78, 16, 17, 22, 58, 30]
print(numpy_choice(population, weights, k))
# [ 9 61  1 18 41 89 55  4 53 40]
print(numba_choice(population, weights, k))
# [66 82 91 62  9 56 71 14 32 26]

%timeit python_choice(population, weights, k)
# 198 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit numpy_choice(population, weights, k)
# 13.4 ms ± 65.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit numba_choice(population, weights, k)
# 2.08 ms ± 27.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

EDIT: Here is how it could go without Numba:

```py
import numpy as np

def loop_choice(population, weights, k):
    wc = np.cumsum(weights)
    m = wc[-1]
    sample = np.empty(k, population.dtype)
    sample_idx = np.full(k, -1, np.int32)
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        r = m * np.random.rand()
        idx = np.searchsorted(wc, r, side='right')
        if np.isin(idx, sample_idx):
            continue
        sample[i] = population[idx]
        sample_idx[i] = population[idx]
        i += 1
    return sample

# Setup from before...
%timeit loop_choice(population, weights, k)
# 3.55 ms ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

EDIT: Just a small test to check the samples are adjusted to the weights:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
n = 200
population = np.arange(n)
weights = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)) + 1
k = 15
r = 1600
a = np.zeros(n, np.int32)
for _ in range(r):
    c = numba_choice(population, weights, k)
    np.add.at(a, c, 1)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(weights / weights.sum(), label='Weights')
plt.plot(a / (k * r), label='Samples')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Sample result]

Comment: thank you, that does improve the speed significantly. I am wondering if I can improve that even further by caching some values. I will give it a try

Comment: Cumsum in Numba is quite slow, but you can write it out using a simple loop like that `wc = np.empty(len(weights) + 1, weights.dtype);wc[0]=0;acc=0;for i in range(weights.shape[0]):;acc+=weights[i];wc[i+1]=acc`

Comment: @max9111 I just tested that but it doesn't seem to make a difference in my measurements (using NumPy 1.18.1 and Numba 0.48.0 with Anaconda for Windows). Maybe it got better?

Comment: @Nik Turns out I didn't need to do that thing with the extra zero at the beginning of `wc`, meaning I can save the extra intermediate array in Numba, so now that's faster. I am currently checking whether this really gives a fair sample though...

Comment: After each draw, one weight is increased. So in theory the cumulative sum does not have to be recalculated for the entire weights vector after each draw but only for the ones after the increased value. But I don't know if this can speed up the process

Comment: @Nik You could pass the both the array of weights and the array of accumulated weights to the function, plus an index indicating from which position you need to update the accumulated weights. In the first call, you pass an empty array of accumulated weights and index 0, then change the index accordingly. In the function, if the update index is 0 then initialize the first accumulated weight value, then update from the given index to the end in a loop. Might save a little bit of time in Numba (in Python `np.cumsum` may be faster than the loop, but use the `out` parameter to reuse the array).

Comment: @Nik Yes it is very important to know that only one weight is increased after a draw. You can save a lot of time if you only update the weights and accumulated weights.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be bug in both of these implementations -- for me it seems `continue` is not actually implementing sampling with replacement (it doesn't seem to have an effect; I still get duplicate indices).

Building on @jdehesa's answer, here's a version with (optional) sampling without replacement (note: it returns the indices rather than samples from an array, but this is an easy change to make).

```py
@nb.njit
def nb_choice(max_n, k=1, weights=None, replace=False):
    '''
    Choose k samples from max_n values, with optional weights and replacement.
    
    Args:
        max_n (int): the maximum index to choose
        k (int): number of samples
        weights (array): weight of each index, if not uniform
        replace (bool): whether to sample with replacement
    '''
    # Get cumulative weights
    if weights is None:
        weights = np.full(int(max_n), 1.0)
    cumweights = np.cumsum(weights)
    
    maxweight = cumweights[-1] # Total of weights
    inds = np.full(k, -1, dtype=np.int64) # Arrays of sample and sampled indices
        
    # Sample
    i = 0
    while i < k:
        
        # Find the index
        r = maxweight * np.random.rand() # Pick random weight value
        ind = np.searchsorted(cumweights, r, side='right') # Get corresponding index
        
        # Optionally sample without replacement
        found = False
        if not replace:
            for j in range(i):
                if inds[j] == ind:
                    found = True
                    continue
        if not found:
            inds[i] = ind
            i += 1

    return inds
```

Example:

```py
n = 1_000_000
population = np.arange(n)
weights = np.random.rand(n)
k = 10
samples = population[nb_choice(n, k, weights)]

%timeit nb_choice(n, k, weights, replace=False)
446 µs ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```